# System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper creates a link with querystrings in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

When using WebAPI 2 and Attribute Routing, a call to UrlHelper.Link returns a route url with querystring attributes.  The same code when using convention based routing returns the route wi the slashes as expected.

For example -

Attribute Routing: http://a.domain.com/api/foods?foodid=1

Convention Routing: http://a.domain.com/api/foods/1

Anyone know how to tell the UrlHelper to not use query strings when using attribute routing?

I am trying to convert some sample code from a pluralsight video into Web API 2.

You can get the code I am using here:

https://github.com/PriceIsByte/WebAPI/tree/issue/1/attribute_routing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find the answer already. Here is mine though.

You must have an optional parameter in your route and also add a name to it. In your case it would be something like this

```
[Route("{foodid?}", Name="Foo")]
```

That will fix it.